# Rails setup production server on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, deployment, passenger

I spent the last few days trying to find some tutorial on how to properly set up a production server for rails with RVM + Apache + Passenger + MySQL + Auto Deploy (Capistrano if possible).

No luck so far, I've read at least 6 - 7 tutorials..

I was wondering if a tutorial that starts from scratch (clean Ubuntu install) to deploy actually exists.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

Comment: @Octopus-Paul good, that would be setting up RVM and rails. Consider MySQL something easy to install so we can discard it, what about Apache, Passenger, and the Auto deploy features?

Comment: Also, I'm wondering about security too...

Comment: What you want to do requires  a lot of study, not just reading some tutorials, but you can find more about what you want here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-apache-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-with-passenger

Comment: @Octopus-Paul which is what I'm looking forward to do, I'm not planning in paying for a Heroku over expensive server, neither care what readings should I do, that's what I'm asking for, what articles / readings would people recommend me